# Magento 2.0.2 Maintenance

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.0.2 maintenance mode flag file is working fine but .maintance.ip is not working.
Please give me exact source code and what IP address need?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you try `magento maintenance:enable [--ip=<ip address> ... --ip=<ip address>] | [ip=none]` as discussed [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html).

I'm not sure whether `maintenance.ip` works anymore. Was that something that worked in Magento 1.x?

Comment: Don't think it worked on M1

Comment: What type of IP address Local or Public?